# How to set number of thread on worker node for dask in cluster mode?

Tags: python-3.x, dask

I have one Dask schedule and 4 workers. Each worker has 4 cpu and 8GB. When I specify the number of thread to run in the workers, it doesn't work. It always just default to the number of cpu(4). Here is how I did it

```
with dask.config.set(pool=ThreadPool(8)):
   bag = db.from_sequence(archives)
   bag.map_partitions(extract_archives).compute()
```

When I change to use number_workers, it is still the same.

```
with dask.config.set(num_workers=8):
   bag = db.from_sequence(archives)
   bag.map_partitions(extract_archives).compute()
```

How to set the number of thread running in the worker node? I am using Dask with python 3.7.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the number of threads when you set up a dask worker process.

```
$ dask-worker --help | grep threads
  --nthreads INTEGER            Number of threads per process.
```